# How to skip Target in .csproj when --no-build is passed?

Tags: .net, .net-core, csproj, dotnet-publish, dotnet-build

How can I stop commands in `<Exec>` tags within a `<Target>` in my .csproj file from running when I run `dotnet publish --no-build ...`? Can I stop the entire `<Target>` section from being used?

Sample:

```xml
<Target Name="BuildSpa" BeforeTargets="Build" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish" Condition="'$(Configuration.ToUpper())' == 'RELEASE'">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The CLI argument `--no-build` sets the msbuild property `NoBuild` to true](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/c2aad5bc5973301107271a31cbbcb77fa423113e/src/Cli/dotnet/commands/dotnet-publish/PublishCommandParser.cs#L31-L32):

```cs
        public static readonly Option NoBuildOption = new Option<bool>("--no-build", LocalizableStrings.NoBuildOptionDescription)
            .ForwardAs("-property:NoBuild=true");
```

The [dotnet docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets) also call this out:

> This can be avoided by passing `--no-build` property to `dotnet.exe`, which is the equivalent of setting `<NoBuild>true</NoBuild>` in your project file, along with setting `<IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>` in the project file.

You should be able to test for that property in your `Condition` check:

```xml
<Target ... Condition="'$(Configuration.ToUpper())' == 'RELEASE' and '$(NoBuild)' != 'true' ">
...
```

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for the quick response!